How to mimic pushd/popd when they're not available?
Edit
I'll leave this question open, but the answer seems to be "Use another shell" or use a Shell utility (such as the original function I wrote).
Background
Long story short, I'm using an Alpine container that has BusyBox as its Shell implementation. Honestly, the more I've used it, the more comfortable I've become with it, but it's missing one of my preferred Shell builtins: pushd and popd. I wrote a simplistic implementation in a *.sh file, and you can find it below.
Question
How do I persist the stack with proper isolation between multiple processes and users?
Original Code
pushd() {
    if ! test -f ~/pushd; then
        echo -n "$(pwd)" > ~/pushd
    else
        echo -n "$(pwd):$(cat ~/pushd)" > ~/pushd
    fi

    cd "$1"
}

popd() {
    if ! test -f ~/pushd; then
        return 0;
    fi

    cd "$(cut -d ':' -f1 ~/pushd)"
    echo -n "$(cut -d ':' -f2- ~/pushd)" > ~/pushd

    if test $(stat -c '%s' ~/pushd) -eq 0; then
        rm ~/pushd
    fi
}

Problems
Given the nature of a Docker container, it will generally be single-user, but it can spawn multiple shells and sub-shells, so I wanted to be able to support that. However, when I looked into the GNU Bash implementation of pushd/popd, it relies on a persistent data store that resides as a runtime allocation of the shell itself. Writing an application that provides this capability as a CLI tool means it will live only long enough for the directory change.
As you can see in my naive solution, I'm writing the "stack" to a file and using cut to grab the previous location. Is this the approach I should use? Should I switch to a binary encoding, or would a raw string be sufficient? Is there an API for me to leverage the internals of BusyBox for persisting this stack for the lifetime of the current shell?

You can't do this in a program. Working directory manipulation has to be built into the shell. Directory changes are inherited by child processes, but have no effect on the parent process.

You can do it in a shell function, since this executes in the shell process.

Why not just install a shell more suited to interactive use in the container?

you could emulate a stack with something like POSIX-arrays

@chepner I'm open to suggestions. Alpine has been the gold standard, in my mind, for lightweight containers. For example, the node:lts-alpine image weighs in at 132MB while node:lts is 1.09GB. I'll write a short Shell script to give me pushd and popd before I explode my image size by 10x.

General note: prefer $PWD to $(pwd). And when you can, NUL-delimit lists of paths when you're storing them in a file, since a NUL is the only character that can't exist inside a path; even newlines are completely legal, and if you're dealing with things like upload directories where an untrusted user could create content with arbitrary names that can be a very real attack vector. ("When you can" because baseline POSIX tools don't have good support for working with NUL-delimited content; this is one of the places where bash and GNU extensions add real and significant value).

That said, pushd and popd are interactive extensions; it's not good form to assume they'll be available in noninteractive shells / during script execution even iin bash, and personally, I rarely find myself missing them -- put things that need to be run in a different directory inside a subshell, and when that subshell exits you're back to the old directory "for free".

@CharlesDuffy the problem I have with the subshell idea is that it adds to the complexity of an already complex process. My Docker container is running in a CI/CD pipeline. I navigate into the directory to perform some action on what is there, but for exporting artifacts I need to be at the project root. Further, I don't know the actual project root (the pipeline runner generates a mount that points to the working directory of the container) and there are multiple possibilities for number of sub-folders. Using pushd/popd simplifies all of this in my case.

If you want to store the project root, which the CI/CD runner invokes your code in, why not run projectRoot=$PWD up at the front of the script? That way you don't need to popd back to it but can reference it directly as-needed.

@CharlesDuffy great suggestion. I'll consider using that in a future revision.
